# Angular- I got 'undefined' as an output of an array object while I have data in my array object

Tags: arrays, angular, api, object

i have an API whose response is given below in the screenshot. I want to fetch data of my array object and display on the web page. But I got undefined as an output, while i have data in my array object. Please tell me where am doing wrong.

services code:

```
testfxn(){
  return(
    this.apiCallService.GET(`${this.myService.myendpoint.xyz}`)
    .pipe(
      map((testData)=>{
        let testresp=testData.response[4];
        return testresp;
      })
    )
  );
}
```

component.ts:

```
    testing(){
        this.reportService.testfxn().subscribe((r)=>{
          this.resp=r
          console.log(this.resp)
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
testing(){
    this.reportService.testfxn().subscribe((data) => {
      this.testingdate=data;
      console.log(this.testingdate);
    });
  }
```

`testfxn()` is an asynchronous function. It is possible that  your `console.log` gets executed before the function returns data and is consumed by `subscribe()`

Comment: still got the same output

Comment: i am unable to console.log(testData) under my service.ts file. IDE doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: Wait, Your `testData.userLogtime[0]` doesn't have `bifurData` object. Did you mean `data.date`?

Comment: date is the property of my array object, the name of array object is userLogtime as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: Yeah. You're returning 1st object from `userLogtime` array from the service. In your component, you're trying to access `bifurData` which is not a property of the object you're returning.

Comment: okay, so what's the solution for this.Basically i want to fetch first prop of userLogtime and later on fetch the date prop of every of every object of userLogtime

Comment: Remove `bifurData;` from data. I've updated the answer

Comment: by doing this i got an empty array as an output